# UITableViewCell fill color with animation

Tags: ios, uicolor, uitableview, ios-animations

Starting from the right end, I have to fill the color in `UITableViewCell` (or to say it better, change the background of `UITableViewCell` starting from right to left in a small duration). How may I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite easy.

Just put a view in the background, starting with a 0 width and on the right of the tableview/tableview cell, then animate it to the full width of the superview.

Code snippet (in form of a Swift playground)

import UIKit
import XCPlayground

```
let tableView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

var animatedBackroundColorView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.frame.width, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.width, height: tableView.frame.height))
animatedBackroundColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
tableView.addSubview(animatedBackroundColorView)
UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { () -> Void in
    animatedBackroundColorView.frame = tableView.frame
}
XCPShowView("identifier", view: tableView)
```

Rending: [image]

Comment: I added the snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width + 1,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:yourColor];
[cell addSubview:backgroundView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
     CGRect rect = backgroundView.frame;
     rect.origin.x = 0;
     [backgroundView setFrame:rect];
} completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked (Fill the background color from right to left).